# Set private key password for mysql using ssl

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, ssl

```
2016-05-09T20:05:05.772747Z 0 [ERROR] SSL error: Unable to get private key from 'server-key.pem'
2016-05-09T20:05:05.772764Z 0 [Warning] Failed to set up SSL because of the following SSL library error: Unable to get private key
```

My installation correctly locates the certificate files however it does not start SSL as it is unable to get the pass phrase for the private key.

How can I configure a passphrase in the mysql configuration?

I have tried removing the passphrase from the key but openssl on ubuntu 16.04 requires a minimum passphrase length of 4 characters.

Comment: How are you attempting to remove the passphrase from the key in `server-key.pem`?

Comment: openssl rsa -in infile -out outfile

Comment: Interesting.  On an Ubuntu 16.04 instance, I generated a key using `openssl genrsa -des3 -out key.pem 2048`, gave it a passphrase, then removed that passphrase using `openssl rsa -in key.pem -out key.pem.new`; I was prompted for the passphrase for _reading_ `key.pem`, but after that, `key.pem.new` contained the passphrase-less key.

Comment: Very, is there some way to turn off the checking that is set on your system?

Comment: "Turn off the checking"? Once you have typed in the passphrase and have the `key.pem.new`, you should be able to use that `key.pem.new` in your MySQL configuration, and MySQL should then be able to read the private key without needing the passphrase.

Comment: Does not allow me to create the key without minimum 4 character passphrase

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17704325/mysql-ssl-remote-connection-error-unable-to-get-private-key/17790729#17790729) solved it for me (removing the passphrase from the server-key).

Answer (score 2):

I had to make sure that mysql owned the .pem files by cd to directory that contains the .pem files and:

```
chown -R mysql .
chgrp -R mysql .
```

After doing that the problem was solved.